# Notify property in another class when property has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class which is a collection (`MapAdapter`) and takes a collection as a constructor parameter .MapAdater adds a Map object on CollectionChanged:

```
public MapAdapter(UndoRedoCollection undoRedoCollection)
 {
    this.undoRedoCollection = undoRedoCollection;
    this.undoRedoCollection.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
  }
```

This is my collection changed event where the Map objects are added:

```
   private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      GetMapRules(TurbineUndoRedoCollection);

   }

private void GetMapRules(UndoRedoCollection undoRedoCollection)
 {
    foreach (var item in undoRedoCollection)
    {
        this.Add(new Map(item));
       }
    }
```

I have a property on MapAdapter which determines whether the layer is visible on a map:

```
 public bool IsLayerVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isLayerVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isLayerVisible = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsLayerVisible"));
            }
        }
```

I have a similar property on my `Map` class. I need to listen to the `IsLayerVisible` Property on my `MapAdapter` and change `IsLayerVisible` on each of my maps within the `MapAdapter` collection. The reason being is that I have a control which draws an image and is passed in a `Map`, it knows nothing of the `MapAdater` therefore I cannot control when & when not to draw based on visibility.

Comment: So what's not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

If the title of your post is provides any clues as to what you're trying to do then all you need to do is implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and fire the `PropertyChanged` event when the value of your property changes.

Then, modify your Map's constructor to accept a `MapAdapter` instance. You don't need to hold a reference to the `MapAdapter` within `Map`, just use it to wire up the event handler for the `PropertyChanged` event against your `MapAdapter`.

Here is an example of what the `Map` class might look like...

```
public class Map
{
    public Map(object item, MapAdapter adapter)
    {
        ...
        adapter.PropertyChanged += this.AdapterPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void AdapterPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArg e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsLayerVisible")
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

And then update your `GetMapRules` method like so...

```
private void GetMapRules(UndoRedoCollection undoRedoCollection)
{
    foreach (var item in undoRedoCollection)
    {
        this.Add(new Map(item, this));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: INPC is implemented in the MapAdapter & I'm invoking PropertyChanged on the setter of IsLayerVisible. I'm trying to use the PropertyChangedEventManager in the Map class however the Map class has no knowledge of the MapAdapter instance therefore I can't listen to it? PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(? ,this, "IsLayerVisible");

Comment: Can you pass a reference of MapAdapter to Map in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Look up pub-sub or Event Aggregator patterns.

Specifically, [Prism has an implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) that may be of interest.

This [link](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html) has a standalone example of this pattern that may be instructive as well.